# QStackedLayout setAlignment function does nothing

Tags: c++, qt

hope you're doing well.

I'm trying to right align two widgets contained in a QStackedLayout.
The two widgets are resize to be square, so they don't take all the place in the layout.

I tried :

```
stacked_layout->setAlignment(widget1, Qt::AlignRight)
```

I also tried to resize the QStackedLayout itself with setGeometry, but it doesn't resize well.

> Place the QProgressBar in a container (i.e. QWidget) that allows it to be centered with an additional layout.

doesn't work either. Or maybe I didn't understand the answer. The only item that can be add to a QStackedLayout is QWidget. And "an additional layout" isn't clear either.

Here's what you could do to reproduce the problem

```
QStackedLayout *stacked_layout = new QStackedLayout();    
QLabel *label = new QLabel(QPixmap("image")); 
stacked_layout->addWidget(label);
label->setFixedSize(label->size().height(), label->size().height());
stacked_layout->setAlignment(label, Qt::AlignRight);
```

The label should be align to the right but it does absolutely nothing.

Any idea please ?